# Want to implement application on java 1.7 from 1.6

Tags: java, swing

Application I am working on is desktop application based on healthcare. It is fully tested on `java 1.6` now we want to implement it on `java 1.7` so how much effort we need to test and implement this application on `java 1.7`. Is anything special that we need to keep in mind to deploy on this version?

Comment: If you haven't used any old deprecated methods in your app, try running it in Java 7. There should not be any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 should be fully backward compatible with your Java 6 code.

The first step is to compile the source under JDK 7.  If that succeeds, you should be good to go.

You should check the [JDK 7 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-429209.html) to see about new features that you may want to leverage in the future.

Answer (score 1):

All java newer version support backward compatibility... So if it works on 1.6 it will work on 1.7 too with enhanced performance.

Answer (score 1):

All the features of 1.6 are also present in 1.7 so it will be compatible to 1.7 also.Backward compatibility becomes an issue here is not the the case